# Изменение размера изображения PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в php способ (который работает достаточно быстро), чтобы изменить размер изображения. Меня не интересует тот способ, в котором изображение нужно сначало создать imagecreatefromgif (так как таким способом при изменении размеров более 15 картинок скрипт значительно замедляется в скорости). И ещё вопрос, можно ли как-нибудь в php вернуть высоту и ширину изображения (без его создания imagecreatefromgif).

Comment: Посмотрите на phpThumb: http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- узнать размер: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php
- сделать превью: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-thumbnail.php
- сделать превью: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php
- и прочие функции: https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Comment: узнать размер: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php
Перед тем как узнать высоту и ширину, эта функция создаёт новое изображение (подобно imagecreatefromjpeg), она работает также медленно

Comment: видимо никак его не узнать без создания изображения. поэтому, чтобы не нагружать постоянно сервер, эти размеры вычисляют 1 раз и сохраняют куда-то отдельно. в базу или в файл.

Answer (score 1):

Может эта библиотека подойдет:
http://www.imagemagick.org/

Answer (score 0):

Может быть вот эта библиотека будет вам полезна - https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage